# call multiple functions from same dll

Tags: c, windows, winapi, dll

This could be a simple one.. I searched for an answer in SO and couldnt find what am looking for and thats why I posted a question here. Following are my doubts,

I'm developing an application where I'm using Windows default dlls. I'm using multiple functions from the same loaded dll. For example:

```
HINSTANCE hinstLib;
hinstLib = LoadLibrary( "Crypt32.dll" );
```

And later use the below code to export the function:

```
CertOpenStore = (fptr1)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "CertOpenStore");
```

Now I want to use another function from the same dll. How would I do as above in cases like this:

```
CertAddEncodedCertificateToStore(CertOpenSystemStore(0,"TrustedPublisher"),PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING |X509_ASN_ENCODING,pbEncodedCert,dwSize,CERT_STORE_ADD_REPLACE_EXISTING,NULL);
```

where both `CertAddEncodedCertificateToStore` and `CertOpenSystemStore` belong to same dll?

Comment: They same way you did for `CertOpenStore`.

Comment: am loading library into only one handle ( hinstlib ) and how to export for two different functions.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Obviously, you can call GetProcAddress with the same handle as many times as you like.  Why do you think you need to do anything more complicated?

Comment: @hary: you are right Hary. got bit confused with the handle part. and one more doubt is if I want to use another dll I can use a different handle here right??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as you did before but for a different function name:

```
fptr1 OtherFunc = GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "OtherFunc");
```